# VSCode cannot find php executable

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, executable-path

I orginally did not have php installed when I got vs code.  Therefore I installed the PHP IntelliSense extension and installed PHP.  VS Code could still not locate PHP so I realized I had to change the php.validate.executablePath in VS Code.  Which I did and I changed it to the php.exe location.  However it still does not work.  Can someone please give me some insight as to why or a resolution.  The file path is correct in VSCode but still does not work.  Assistance would be appreciated... see screen shot.

[Img of VSCode and File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92WRI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a silly mistake... I just had to add the same exact extention to the php.executablePath and now it works perfectly fine.  See screenshot...

[Resolution Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJoGu.png)

Comment: As the message box in the first screenshot suggest you to fix the problem.

Comment: @axiac not sure what you mean.

Comment: In the image you attached to the question, VSCode clearly tells you in the notification window to set `php.executablePath` with the path of the PHP interpreter. The answer is in the question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that, as mentioned in the answer above.  Just clarifying that the resolution was found.  :)